# Unable to redirect non-www to www in django Nginx project on Digital Ocean

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean

Hello I would be grateful if someone could please help with the following Nginx configuration:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/example

```
server {
    server_name *.example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/admin/pyapps/example/example/static/;
    }

    location /static/admin/ {
        alias /home/admin/pyapps/example/example/static/admin/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/admin/pyapps/example;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}


server {
    if ($host = admin.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = backoffice.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I would like to create a redirection for example.com to https://www.example.com.

Note that I am using django-hosts.

My configuration for django-hosts below:

settings.py

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'example.urls'
ROOT_HOSTCONF = 'example.hosts'
DEFAULT_HOST = 'www'
# DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL = "http://www.example.com:8000"
DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL = "http://www.example.com"
PARENT_HOST = 'example.com'
# HOST_PORT = '8000'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django_hosts.middleware.HostsRequestMiddleware',
    ....
    'django_hosts.middleware.HostsResponseMiddleware',
]
```

hosts.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django_hosts import patterns, host
from example.hostsconf import urls as redirect_urls
from . import admin_urls

host_patterns = patterns('',
    host(r'www', settings.ROOT_URLCONF, name='www'),
    host(r'admin', admin_urls, name='admin'),
    host(r'backoffice', 'backoffice.urls', name="backoffice"),
    host(r'(?!www).*', redirect_urls, name='wildcard'),
)
```

hostsconf/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import wildcard_redirect

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^?P<path>.*)', wildcard_redirect),
]
```

hostsconf/views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL = getattr(settings, "DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL", "http://www.example.com")

def wildcard_redirect(request, path=None):
    new_url = DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL
    if path is not None:
        new_url = DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL + '/' + path
    return HttpResponseRedirect(new_url)
```

I have tried pretty much everything, but I think it might have to do with the django-hosts config.

When I go to https://example.com, it shows me the 'Welcome to nginx' screen instead of redirecting to https://www.example.com.

[image]

When I go to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or to admin.example.com or to backoffice.example.com, the website loads fine.

Someone please assist me. I would like to redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com

Let me know if you need any other configuration from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your second block

````
server {
    if ($host = admin.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = backoffice.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```
````

change `www.example.com` in your condition 
return `https://www.$host$request_uri;`

---

### Edit made by OP

It turns out the above is correct, however I had an additional change to make.

There is a default nginx config file under `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and it is called `default`.

In this file, the server block at the bottom must be removed.

```
    #server {
    #    if ($host = example.com) {
    #        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    #    } # managed by Certbot
    
    
    #       listen 80 ;
    #       listen [::]:80 ;
    #    server_name example.com;
    #    return 404; # managed by Certbot
    
    
    #}
```

What was happening is that this block was running first when requesting `example.com` and it was redirecting to `https://example.com`.

Or maybe I could have edited the server block in the default file. But I did not try it. I prefer to have all the configuration in one place.

Comment: I tried that, but it redirects to https://example.com. Is there any way I can see a log of what is happening when I request example.com?

Comment: have you tried access log in nginx?

Comment: and try to remove *.example.com from server_name of your 80 port block

Comment: Try open it in different browser, `www` is something that you rarely see in modern world, so I'm pretty sure browsers automatically cut it since long ago. Just tried to access this page by adding www, but it redirected me to URL without it. Maybe nginx does actually redirect you to www.* page, but your browser ct it. You also can try to test it via curl or from python code, somewhere you can ensure, that your tool does not do some shady business

Comment: No it does not cut the www. Actually the www page loads correctly. When I do not specify www, that is when I go to example.com, it loads https://example.com which is the nginx successfully installed page. When I go to www.example.com, it loads https://www.example.com which loads correctly.

Comment: I managed to fix it. I updated your answer and marked it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove `example.com` from your first server block as you won't serve anything to this domain without a subdomain for HTTPS.
2. Add the following if statement to the second server block to directly redirect non-www traffic to www HTTPS version:
   `if ($host = example.com) { return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri; }`
3. add a third server block with the following content to redirect HTTPS traffic from non-www to www:

   ```
    server {
        if ($host = example.com) {
            return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
        }

        server_name example.com;
        listen [::]:443;  # if you would like to support IPv6
        listen 443;
        return 404;
    }
   ```

Comment: I just tried this - it still does not redirect to www. I get the nginx page. In the second server block, I add 'if ($host = example.com) { return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri; }'. I add the same thing in the third block. Is that correct?